# ErrorException Attempt to read property "name" on null (View:

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 2 relationships that point to the same User model: operador() and profesional().

```
class Cita extends Model
{

    public function paciente(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Paciente');
        
    }
    
    public function profesional(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
        
    }

    public function operador(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
        
    }
    
}
```

In the view I call them like this:

```
                        @foreach ($comisiones as $comision)
                            <tr>

                            <td>{{ $comision->paciente->name }}</td>
                            
                            <td>{{ $comision->profesional->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $comision->operador->name }}</td>
                            
                            <td>{{ number_format($comision->total, 0, '.', '.') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $comision->estado }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

The program crashes on me when it tries to call $commision->operador->name. If I leave it as a comment it works without problems. But it gives me an error when I have the 2 relations at the same time.

Can I have 2 relationships pointing to the same model? And if not, what alternative do I have? Thanks

Comment: `belongsTo()` by default allows `null`. **You** need to account for that: `{{ $comision->operador ? $comision->operador->name : 'No Operador... }}` or similar.

Comment: In this case it always brings an Id, it is never null.

Comment: But your error is `Attempt to read property 'name' on 'null`, so yes, it very clearly _is_ `null`. One of those `->paciente->name`, `->professional->name` or `->operador->name` is triggering that, but if you check for `null` before trying to access as shown above, you won't encounter that error.

Comment: But it also returns null when the relationship in the model is poorly defined and this is the case.

Comment: you need to rebuild your database . If don't have important data in your app use `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: It _should_ be triggering some kind of error actually. But, regardless, if you allow the columns to be `nullable()` in the database, you're allowing the relationship `$comision->{whatever}` to be `null`, and as I said, **you**, not the system, need to account for that in some way.

Comment: @YasserCHENIKI just rebuilt the database and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @YasserCHENIK Now it worked for me. I rebuilt the database and corrected a field in the controller. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write :

```
public function operador(){
    
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    
}
```

Laravel expects that The Migration (The table citas) has a column named `operador_id`. **So Yes** you can have multiple relationships to the same model.

Answer (score 1):

For the fact that you are using `belongTo` relationship, that means User is the parent model and `Professional` and `Operador` are the child model.

Hence, it is expected that the table for **Professional** has a column called `user_id`, thesame thing for the **Operador** table, it should have `user_id` column.

With this the relationship will work just fine.

***Yes, you can have 2 relationships pointing to the same model.***